# Do essential oils damage climbing ropes?

Tags: gear, climbing, ropes

I have an all natural bug spray that uses distilled water and a combination of four essential oils, and NOT containing DEET. If I spray it on my body and clothing before climbing will these essential oils weaken the fibers of the climbing ropes?

Comment: Does your bug spray actually work? This was my introduction to essential oils: [Using Essential Oils - Ultra Spiritual Life episode 33](https://youtu.be/Q_Ecmciv9zI)

Comment: @Ginji This question is clearly related. But from quickly scanning the answers of this question I do not find (essential) oils addressed. So unless you write up or edit an answer there that clearly addresses this, there is no reason to close this question as duplicate. Closing would lead to this question being unanswered, which would probably deter readers.

Comment: On second thoughts: This is answered in the linked question (voted to close): Oil itself is not a problem. The "essential" part can be almost anything, wikipedia lists one danger as some being flammable at 50degC which a hot abseil device can reach. So I would not take the (admittedly small) risk. Rather use bug deterrent on your clothes where it is anyway much more effective.

Comment: Why would you spray bug spray on a rope?!

Comment: The other questions ask about bug sprays containing deet, which mine don't and I would spray on myself and clothing, and because my clothing would be touching the rope, and my hands may have the bug spray on it, will it weaken the fibers of the rope?

Comment: @gerrit, I had never said spray it on my rope, someone had edited , in which I was saying if I sprayed it, and then used my climbing rope, meaning if I sprayed it on myself and clothing will it damage the fibers of the rope :)

Comment: @imsodin The oil is the main risk factor, the aromatics (the "essential" part) are volatile for a reason, so you smell, they need to evaporate readily and easily, so whilst the risk is there it's small because you're (hopefully) not soaking the rope with the oil so most of the volatile parts should have evaporated away quickly.

Comment: @charlene Well now the answer is a trivial "No" as I do not think you will have your hands soaking of that stuff.

Comment: I would not let lemon oil anywhere near any polymers (eg nylon, polyester, polypropylene). Stuff is a lethal solvent for many plastics. Don't know if your bug spray has lemon oil in, but citrus things seem to often be used for this so thought it might be relevant.